# Sending emails from Visual Studio using Exchange Web Service

Tags: visual-studio, exchangewebservices

I am trying to send email using Exchange Web Service (`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard`) and it is working when I am using Linqpad.

But the same code does not send email when running in Visual Studio. There is no error either.

I am running either app as myself.

Appreciate any idea to troubleshoot this issue.

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016)
{
    Url = new Uri("..."),   
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
};
 
var address = "...";

var message = new EmailMessage(service) 
{ 
    From = address,
    Subject = "test",
    Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, "test")
};

message.ToRecipients.Add(address);

message.Send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Nuget reference in Visual Studio to `Microsoft.Exchange.WebService` and that solved the issue.